# How do I set a label for an equation that does not have number?

Tags: labels

I want to insert a label with the command `\label{aname}` for an equation that doesn't have number(`=\begin{equation*}\end{equation*}`). Is it possible?

when I use the command \begin{equation}, the command `\hyperref{}` works but with the commands \begin{equation*} or `\[ \]`, the command `\hyperref{}` does not work.

Comment: you need to use `\phantomsection\label{key}` otherwise the `\label` has nothing to latch on to.

Comment: @daleif Thankyou very much . Yes it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `equation*` or `\[...\]` there is no counter change for the hyperlink to latch on to (that is how it works with say `equation`, `hyperref` mingles via the counter change).

Therefore you need to provide something for the `\label` to latch on to. The traditional method is `\phantomsection` (bit of a bad name) so you should be able to use

```
\phantomsection\label{key}
```

note that you will probably need to use `\hyperref` or `\pageref` for the hyperlink